# Sub-sites as records

Tags: best-practices, sub-site

I have been sent a solution proposal from a company on how they would build their Sharepoint site.

We need to have a place to store information about a business deviations, such as name, organisation, deviations detail, supporting documents etc and this would follow a small workflow for approval. We also need to do KPI reporting on this data.

In the proposal the supplier would create a master site and for every new deviation a new sub-site would be created.

My gut feeling is that this feels wrong, I would have expected a record to be created within the master site, but since I am no SharePoint developer I am reaching out to you for comments.

Is this approach following best practice?

Thanks in advance
P

Comment: It sounds like overkill to me. I'm surprised they aren't just keeping each "deviation" as a list item, but maybe I don't fully understand what a deviation is and what exactly would be maintained under it. I'm not sure, but it seems you'll run into limitations on how many sub-sites your main will be able to handle. I think I've seen some sort of count on this, but don't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

I think, 1st we need to understand the deviation meaning.One entry of deviation consist of what, few documents(word/excel/pdf) and some details i.e deviations details include,name, reason, date etc. What else will come other than that? How many deviations per month/year?

I am thinking about a Deviation List and one document Library.

- Create  a folder in the Document library for the Deviation name
- You can enter all the meta details in the issue list and put a link
  to documentation folder.
- You can put a approval work flow on the list.

But if they still want to go for subsite, it is still do able as 250,000 is limit.

> The maximum recommended number of sites and subsites is 250,000 sites.
>   You can create a very large total number of web sites by nesting
>   subsites. For example, in a shallow hierarchy with 100 sites, each
>   with 1,000 subsites, you would have a total of 100,000 web sites. Or a
>   deep hierarchy with 100 sites, each with 10 subsite levels would also
>   contain a total of 100,000 web sites.
>   [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#SiteCollection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx#SiteCollection)